# Find time difference in minutes in data frame and add is as a column

Tags: r, time

First, I want to find the **time difference** between tm2 and tm1  **in minutes** in the following data frame (sometimes overnight as in row 2).

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id=1:2, tm1=c("01:00","23:00"), tm2=c("05:00","03:00"))
```

[Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKnP6.png)

Second, I will add it to the data frame "dat1" as an extra column called time_diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the times to POSIXct, subtract them, convert that to doubles as minutes and take it modulo 24 * 60 since we presume that the unstated assumption is that tm2 always comes after tm1.  No packages are used.  Alternately we could use hm from lubridate in place of to_ct.

```
to_ct <- function(x) as.POSIXct(x, format = "%H:%M")
transform(dat1, time_diff = as.double(to_ct(tm2) - to_ct(tm1), "mins") %% (24 * 60))
```

giving:

```
  id   tm1   tm2 time_diff
1  1 01:00 05:00       240
2  2 23:00 03:00       240
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat1 %>% 
  mutate(
    tm1 = as.POSIXlt(tm3, format="%H:%M"),
    tm2 = as.POSIXlt(tm4, format="%H:%M"),
    time_diff = difftime(tm2, tm1, units='mins'))
```

Comment: This give `-1200 mins` as the answer for row 2, as there is no date. The OP said these were from overnight, and not the same day.

Comment: @lab_rat_kid I would say you need one more column to specify the `date`. Otherwise, it can be the second day, third day, or even tenth day. It just hard to tell and make errors.

Comment: agreed. That's why I said that in my answer above. Either another column for date, or preferably both date and time in the one column.

Answer (score 0):

If your times might be from different days, then there is no way that R can know this without also supplying a date.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat1  <- data.frame(tm3 = parse_date_time(c("2020-05-15 01:00",
                                        "2020-05-15 23:00"), 
                                      '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),
                    tm4 = parse_date_time(c("2020-05-15 05:00",
                                        "2020-05-16 03:00"), 
                                      '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

Give you:

```
> dat1
                  tm3                 tm4 time_diff
1 2020-05-15 01:00:00 2020-05-15 05:00:00  240 mins
2 2020-05-15 23:00:00 2020-05-16 03:00:00  240 mins
```